# Converting enum to drop-down with ordering

Tags: c#, enums

I have an extension method which I can use to convert enums into a SelectList which I can feed into the MVC DropDownListFor helper.

My enum values have a particular order, but when displaying the values in a drop-down I want to display a separate order.

In this particular case, I have a 'TaskPriority' enum which looks like this:

```
public enum TaskPriority
{
    [Display(Order = 2)]
    Low,

    [Display(Order = 1)]
    Normal,

    [Display(Order = 3)]
    High
}
```

For the purposes of ordering items by priority, the enum values have to be in the above order. However, when displaying these enum values to the user, I want to display them according to the order specified using the MVC DisplayAttribute which I've used to decorate my enums.

How can I generate a select list which orders the enums according to the display attribute order?

Here is my existing extension code for converting enums into SelectLists:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(@enum => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = GetDisplayName(@enum),
        Value = GetValue(@enum)
    }).ToList();
}

private static string GetValue<TEnum>(TEnum @enum) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    return ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), @enum.ToString())).ToString();
}

private static string GetDisplayName<TEnum>(TEnum @enum) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    return @enum.GetType().GetMember(@enum.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()?
                .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(false)?.Name ?? @enum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my existing code and added a new extension method:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToOrderedSelectList<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>()
        .Select(@enum => new
        {
            enumValue = GetValue(@enum),
            order = GetDisplayOrder(@enum),
            enumText = GetDisplayName(@enum)
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.order)
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.enumText,
            Value = x.enumValue
        }
    ).ToList();
}

private static int GetDisplayOrder<TEnum>(TEnum @enum) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    return @enum.GetType().GetMember(@enum.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()?
                .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(false)?.Order ?? 0;
}
```